# Map Google Sheets columns to MySQL data types

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Given that I have a Google sheet similar to this:

```
ID;username,email,date_created;
hdJNGDyd;user;me@example.com;12/03/2020 4:20:22
...
```

Is there a way to determine the formats of the Sheet columns and list them?

eg.

```
ID - string(8)
username - varchar(34)
email - varchar(255)
date_created - datetime
```

or map the sheet structure to a SQL query similar to:

```
CREATE table MyTable
`ID` varchar(8) NOT NULL
...
```

The length could be for example maximum length of the values in the particular column.

Comment: How do you plan to transfer the data?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a tab with a table listing the data dictionary

However, sheets has a TYPE() function you can use. If you also wanted to get the max length that would require some additional calculations.

[image]

[image]

So as you can see there is no date type and only a number type. Much different than what SQL offers.

In some of my projects I use google app script to get the schema from the MySQL database and then act accordingly

```
function getColTypes(conn, table) {
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var query = "SELECT COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='" + DATABASE + "' AND TABLE_NAME='" + table + "'";
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  var colTypes = [];
  while (rs.next()) {
    colTypes.push(rs.getString(1));
  }
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  return colTypes;
}
```

And this one for the names

```
function getColNames(conn, table) {
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var query = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='" + DATABASE + "' AND TABLE_NAME='" + table + "'";
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  var colNames = [];
  while (rs.next()) {
    colNames.push(rs.getString(1));
  }
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  return colNames;
}
```